# default view on a <div>? without onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onclick

```
onclick=\"showOrderParcelsResultsTable();\"
```

but in html is there a way to give some kind of default view

beacause i need it too show

```
showParcelResultsTable();
```

by default, can i do default=\"showParcelResultsTable();\"  ??
but keeping the onclick at the same time

Comment: when do you want to invoke the function showParcelResultsTable()? on load? every time the showOrderParcelsResultsTable() is invoked?

Comment: I want the showOrderParcelsResultsTable to be onclick and the showParcelResultsTable to be onload but inside the same tab/div

Comment: What does `showOrderParcelsResultsTable` do?  Show us the code.  It sounds like you need to be able to change it to pass in an element reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick happens only when you click on the div.
If what you want is to call showOrderParcelsResultsTable() at first before any action, you should implement in javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
        showParcelResultsTable();
    };
```

(if this function is specific to one item you can use document.getElementById(divId)  and pass it as a parameter to this function, or if you're using jquery

```
$('#divId or .divClass').each(function(){
            showParcelResultsTable();
        };) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `showParcelResultsTable();` in Script tags. Either after the page element or at the top in a ready block.

At the bottom of the page:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    showParcelResultsTable();
</script>
</html>
```

At the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        showParcelResultsTable();
    };
</script>
```